# Godot Engine 4.2. Why window resizing doesn't work

Tags: godot4

All

I'm working on a 2D text game built on a Godot. Viewport size was set as 1920x1080 and all game UI was built for that resolution. Now I'm trying to make it run in window mode and I got some issues with scaling and shrinking.

Is it possible to make it works like it was in Godot 3.5.2?

**mode:** canvas_items
**aspect:** keep
**scale:** 1
**scale_mode:** integer

**What is expected behavior?**
In the window mode I want to use window borders to change the window size without changing node's positions (like it was in Godot 3.5.2, with 2d mode).  Game screen become smaller or bigger on window size changing by dragging it's border.

**What is current behavior?**
In the window mode all elements of the game changing it's positions. Some of them cutted out by window borders.